# Commuter train armoured to cross decaying inner city from suburbs to business district

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a commuter train armoured to cross a decaying inner city from the suburbs to the city business district. The passengers had to take turns "riding shotgun".

This article: [Apple and Google Are Rerouting Their Employee Buses as Attacks Resume](http://fortune.com/2018/01/18/apple-google-bus-attacks/) brought it to mind.

Comment: What about this story is specifically makes it Science Fictional or Fantastical? Right now it sounds like it could easily exist in our real world. Also take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) of things you could add, such as when you read it, what anthology it may have been a part of, etc.

Comment: @Edlothiad, surely works set in dystopian futures count as science fiction, even if there is no other more explicit fantastic element?  John Brunner's *The Sheep Look Up*, for example.

Comment: @Harry I’m not seeing why it should necessarily. Nothing fictional or fantastical about it. Maybe there’s a meta on this.

Comment: I think it would be from the '60s or 70s. Set in USA. My first thought was Harlan Ellison but I don't see any titles of his stories that look likely. It struck me as very dystopian futuristic at the time.

Comment: @Edlothiad, [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5351/5930) is the closest I can find, about, e.g., Mad Max.  Opinions were divided, but the top-voted answer was for inclusion.  Also see the first bullet point on [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5353/5930); granted we can't be sure that the story was marketed as science fiction until we've identified it, but if the OP believes that it was then personally I'm inclined to give them the benefit of the doubt.  (Provided the details given at least *suggest* a science fiction story, which in this case they do.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston it would be worth noting that there are no close votes on the question. If I had reason to believe it was strictly off-topic I would’ve cast one, hence my use of the word _specifically_, dystopian futures may be deemed science fictional, but they don’t have to be. But I see no harm in the question existing until the story is identified.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that it is a short story based on the "Car Wars" board game by Steve Jackson.
They also published a Magazine of game ideas and short stories 4x a year called "American AutoDuel Quarterly" (AADQ) that lasted for 10 years. (1983-1992)

Society is collapsing (not as bad as Road Warrior) but just about every one has weapons built into to their cars/trucks/motorcycles, etc to protect themselves on the road.

Pros
The story sounds Very much like the sort of stories they would have included in the magazine.

Cons
The premise of the game and magazine is its set in 2030s

Comment: I found a couple of AutoDuel Quarterlys [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/330767810/Autoduel-Quarterly-10-3) and [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/330767402/Autoduel-Quarterly-6-4).